# My application is hung and windbg dump analysis shows all threads are in suspended/unfrozen state. What does it mean?

Tags: debugging, windbg, adplus

My outlook addin application is hung and windbg hang dump analysis shows all threads are in suspended/unfrozen state. The errors in the event viewer and process monitor shows hundreds of registry lookup failures and disk access failures. What does the threads' suspended/unfrozen state mean?

Answer (score 2):

The F1 help from WinDBG explains the following in greater detail if you look for 'Controlling Processes and Threads' link from '~ (Thread Status) command' under Index tab.
Also there is a [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So firstly freezing has no meaning unless you have a debugger attached so only a debugger can freeze or unfreeze a thread.

Suspended threads have a suspend count such that when the count goes to 0 resumes execution for that thread if appropriate, higher than 0 will suspend the thread.

Typically when you attach the debugger then it will increase the suspend count for each thread by 1 as you are invasively debugging the application or you have hit a breakpoint.

So frozen/unfrozen state only has meaning when you have the debugger attached and have hit a breakpoint, suspended/unsuspended is the suspend count for each thread when your application is running.

Hope this helps.

Comment: just wanted to share this link, as this answer and the link together helped me: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539289(v=vs.85).aspx